# Not showing clickable links in search results

Tags: search

I'm fairly new to Drupal but have gotten a hang of installing modules and setting up there configuration pages.
The company site i'm working on is running on Drupal 7.1.4 and is using Node Search to look through books that they have created for documentation of their products. The problem with the node search was the lack of proper phrase search and partial words not being found.  I have Search API, Search Facets, Search Pages and Fuzzy Search modules installed and it appears to be working but not as expected.

Unfortunately the results come back as unclickable links, with some results coming back as text only excerpts of certain books and most results coming back as what appears to be just the author name with a time stamp of the books that are available.

I'm having a bit of trouble finding a way to display these search results as proper links and text excerpts with highlighted search terms.

Was hoping someone here would be able to assist.

Answer (score 0):

A couple of possibilities. Is the site using Search API views? If so perhaps there is a search results view that you can adjust.

Another idea might be that someone has customized the search results templates in the theme to be unlinked or otherwise weird. Check in your theme folder for any search related templates.